# Trying to access json array element but it returns undefined

Tags: arrays, json

I am filling a **json array** with data from an sql query, but when i try to use on of the elements it comes out **undefined**.

```
$select = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'grade', 'site_id', 'role_id', 'school_id', 'email', 'sites.alias'];

        $usersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
        $sitesTable = TableRegistry::get('Sites');
        $users = $usersTable->find('all')
                            ->select($select)
                            ->innerjoin('sites', 'Users.site_id = sites.id')
                            ->where(['first_name LIKE' => '%'.$filter.'%'])
                            ->orWhere(['last_name LIKE' => '%'.$filter.'%'])
                            ->andWhere($where);

        $total = $users->count();

        if(isset($users) && !empty($users)) {
            echo json_encode($users);
        } else {
            $errors = ['No users found'];
            echo json_encode($errors);
        }
```

When I try to access the sites.alias in my html code it come out **undefined**.

Comment: Every other element is fine. Just the alias is returning undefined. I thought maybe it was because the value in the table was null, so I put something into the table value but it still returns undefined.

Comment: Please check the column name again or add into the question @bryan Mobbs

Comment: the column name i am trying to get it alias on a table called sites.

Comment: add your both table details plz cannot find the root cause

Comment: we are using cakephp

Comment: this is the setup for the sites table: CREATE TABLE `sites` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `physical_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cms_site_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cms_cal_api_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `alias` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: this is the users table: CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `role_id` int(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `school_id` varchar(24) DEFAULT NULL,
  `state_school_id` text,
  `first_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `last_name` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `username` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

Comment: i apologize if i am unclear. this is all still very new to me.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I think i have figured it out. When it is going into the $users array, the sites.alias was going is as an array itself. I just needed to access it by using $().each() loop then used val['sites'].alias to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this Laravel? If yes, try using ->join('sites', 'users.site_id', '=', 'sites.id') instead of that innerjoin.

Comment: its the same remove your answer and add into comments